# How to capture the userid and productid and store in to database

Tags: vb.net

http://localhost:2000/RegisteredUsers/ProductsDetails.aspx?PublicationID=23
Login user: Userone

Can someone help me how to capture the publicationID which is 23 and the loginuser "Userone" and store them in the database by using vb.net

I am new to this and i really appreciate your help.

Comment: You need to ask the question properly. Currently Its very unclear of what you are asking. Share some more details.

Answer (score 1):

Have you heard the concept of [`QueryString`?](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.querystring(v=vs.110).aspx)

You can capture the value like

```
string v = Request.QueryString["PublicationID"];
if (v != null)
{
    Response.Write("param is ");
    Response.Write(v);
}
```